# what is function that i can use instead of Do events (used in vb6.0) in (vb2010)

Tags: vb.net, vb6

```
for a=0 to 1000
lable.text=a
next
```

Above loop does not update the  text status of `lable`, while loop is running, it updates only at the end of for loop, but I tried with vb6.0 it is possible by using Do events. But I don't know what is the function in VB2010 beta 2.

Any ideas on how to implement this loop in VB2010?

Answer (score 1):

You could try

[Application.DoEvents()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx)

Or even

[lable.Refresh()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: Is not good to use Application.Doevents. Better use Control.Update Bye

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the way you think about this sort of problem in .NET - DoEvents was a hack to deal with the lack of threading in VB, useful but not a good solution.

To run a processor intensive task while keeping the UI responsive you need to use multi-threading, you kick off the intensive work in a separate thread and update the UI in the main thread.

Easiest way to do this is using the BackgroundWorker class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(VS.100).aspx

Your loop would raise ReportProgress events which your UI code would use to update the label.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Application.DoEvents()` in .Net - but you really probably shouldn't.  It can cause all sorts of strange behaviour that will be a nightmare to debug.  I've seen button's OnClick event firing when the button is disabled (as an example) and ultimately traced it back to calling DoEvents().

If your goal is really just to count and update a label - use a `Timer`.

If you are doing meaningful work - you should look into multithreading.

The `BackgroundWorker` class makes this pretty darn easy - you can have it report progress and update your control.  If you aren't using an old version of the .NET Framework - you can use a `Task` as well.

Having said all of that - no matter what approach you take - you won't be able to see much of anything inside a loop like you've provided in your example.  It will simply happen too fast (unless you use a timer and set the Tick value appropriately).

**Example Using a Timer**
The easiest way to do this is in the Form Designer - drag a Timer Component (under the Components group) onto your form.  You can edit the properties and give it an appropriate name and set the Tick value to something like 500 (that's the tick interval in milliseconds).  Set the Enabled value to True.

Now click the Timer control, and pull up the Properties window.  Click on the Events Icon and double click the `Tick` Textbox.  This should create the default handler for you.

Modify the code to look like this:

```
Private A As Integer

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ' Update the text
    Label1.Text = A.ToString
    A += 1

    ' Stop the timer 
    If A >= 1000 Then
        Timer1.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but I'll try to explain what I understood. The loop *actually* updates it, but it happens so fast that you only see the final value. I don't know the VB equilevant of `sleep()` method, but you should be able to find it in web pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Its not the text is not getting changed but its getting overwritten when you loop it each time. If you want to display 0 to 1000 in the label then you have to append the value.